# Some questions about FASM

Tags: assembly, fasm

I am a newbie to the world of assembly and will like to ask some few questions about FASM before I waste my time and sanity in learning it.

1. I read that FASM can output COFF .obj file. Can this .obj file be linked together with other .obj files generated from other programs like GoRC (Resource Compiler).
2. How can executable generated with FASM be made UAC aware (like making them run with admin privilege) in Windows
3. Where can I find a Step by Step tutorial of asm in FASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can link the result COFF object files to any other compatible object file. Although the main power and unique feature of FASM is how good it is able to create directly executable files. If you want to create full assembly application, you simply don't need the link stage. FASM can create itself everything. The only reason for link stage to be used is in order to use object files created by other compilers - C/C++/Pascal, etc.
2. I think UAC is a matter of OS, not the compiler. Especially for Windows, FASM creates standard PE executable files. If you are using linker, then it is responsible for the executable file creation.
3. Where actually you want to arrive following this "step" by "step" tutorial? There is a very full user manual in every FASM package downloaded and there is a [Documentation](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php) page on the flat assembler site. There is a fine [message board](http://board.flatassembler.net/) where you can ask questions as well.

Comment: Thanks for this... Read further on UAC and learnt an application can be made UAC aware by embedding a manifest in the application resource. The manifest is actually an XML so am a little bit confused on how to embed this into the resource.

Comment: @Osofem I am working on Linux recently but I am sure there was a discussion on this topic on FASM message board.